# Rails 3: token fields, need a little help tweaking my code

Tags: jquery, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, token

Right now I've got a working setup for jquery token fields (using jquery_token_input gem) on my author model and my post model, using a has_many through :authorships, in other words you start typing the author's name and it will appear and you select it. If you get no results you can choose 'Add: new_name' instead and it will create a new author.

I'd like to use this same method for users to assign a 'collection' name just like they do authors, BUT tweak it so only collections for a single user are searched and displayed/created.

Do I need to assign a user_id coloumn to the collection model when I call create!? How would I modify the "name like ?", , "%#{params[:q]}%" to also include the user_id of the current_user?

Really appreciate any insight or ideas.

```
##

class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @artists = Artist.where("name ilike ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
    results = @artists.map(&:attributes)
    results << {:name => "Add: #{params[:q]}", :id => "CREATE_#{params[:q]}_END"}

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => results }
    end
  end


## Post model

   has_many :artistizations
   has_many :artists, :through => :artistizations 
   attr_reader :artist_tokens

   def artist_tokens=(ids)
     ids.gsub!(/CREATE_(.+?)_END/) do
       Artist.create!(:name => $1).id
     end
     self.artist_ids = ids.split(",")
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this too. I am trying to do this with a habtm tho.
Check your code:

```
@artists = Artist.where("name ilike ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
```

`ilike` - should this be `like`?

Ah, ilike is for Postgres.